Trino | Hive | Minio - Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
Somewhere in the weeds between Trino, Hive Metastore, and Minio is this SSL issue. The exception originates from the following query:
    create schema minio.ukhd
    with (location = 's3a://bronze/ukhd');`

The stacktrace I'm getting is:
    org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [65536]: Query failed (#20240627_164652_00000_wnvna): Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:133)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:615)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$2(SQLQueryJob.java:506)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:192)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:525)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:977)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:4176)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:123)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:192)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:121)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:5154)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Query failed (#20240627_164652_00000_wnvna): Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
    at io.trino.jdbc.AbstractTrinoResultSet.resultsException(AbstractTrinoResultSet.java:1937)
    at io.trino.jdbc.TrinoResultSet$ResultsPageIterator.computeNext(TrinoResultSet.java:294)
    at io.trino.jdbc.TrinoResultSet$ResultsPageIterator.computeNext(TrinoResultSet.java:254)
    at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.guava.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:145)
    at io.trino.jdbc.$internal.guava.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:140)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.lambda$initPartialTraversalState$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.fillBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.doAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$1Adapter.hasNext(Unknown Source)
    at io.trino.jdbc.TrinoResultSet$AsyncIterator.lambda$new$1(TrinoResultSet.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1219)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1165)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:814)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:561)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:541)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5558)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5505)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjectsV2(AmazonS3Client.java:1002)
    at io.trino.hdfs.s3.TrinoS3FileSystem.listObjects(TrinoS3FileSystem.java:866)
    at io.trino.hdfs.s3.TrinoS3FileSystem.listPath(TrinoS3FileSystem.java:841)
    at io.trino.hdfs.s3.TrinoS3FileSystem.listLocatedStatus(TrinoS3FileSystem.java:463)
    at io.trino.hdfs.s3.TrinoS3FileSystem.listStatus(TrinoS3FileSystem.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatusBatch(FileSystem.java:2029)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$DirListingIterator.<init>(FileSystem.java:2280)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatusIterator(FileSystem.java:2324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.listStatusIterator(FilterFileSystem.java:294)
    at io.trino.filesystem.hdfs.HdfsFileSystem.lambda$directoryExists$6(HdfsFileSystem.java:264)
    at io.trino.hdfs.authentication.NoHdfsAuthentication.doAs(NoHdfsAuthentication.java:27)
    at io.trino.hdfs.HdfsEnvironment.doAs(HdfsEnvironment.java:134)
    at io.trino.filesystem.hdfs.HdfsFileSystem.directoryExists(HdfsFileSystem.java:260)
    at io.trino.filesystem.manager.SwitchingFileSystem.directoryExists(SwitchingFileSystem.java:117)
    at io.trino.filesystem.tracing.TracingFileSystem.lambda$directoryExists$5(TracingFileSystem.java:119)
    at io.trino.filesystem.tracing.Tracing.withTracing(Tracing.java:47)
    at io.trino.filesystem.tracing.TracingFileSystem.directoryExists(TracingFileSystem.java:119)
    at io.trino.plugin.hive.HiveMetadata.lambda$createSchema$22(HiveMetadata.java:956)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
    at io.trino.plugin.hive.HiveMetadata.createSchema(HiveMetadata.java:954)
    at io.trino.plugin.base.classloader.ClassLoaderSafeConnectorMetadata.createSchema(ClassLoaderSafeConnectorMetadata.java:409)
    at io.trino.tracing.TracingConnectorMetadata.createSchema(TracingConnectorMetadata.java:339)
    at io.trino.metadata.MetadataManager.createSchema(MetadataManager.java:786)
    at io.trino.tracing.TracingMetadata.createSchema(TracingMetadata.java:373)
    at io.trino.execution.CreateSchemaTask.internalExecute(CreateSchemaTask.java:128)
    at io.trino.execution.CreateSchemaTask.execute(CreateSchemaTask.java:82)
    at io.trino.execution.CreateSchemaTask.execute(CreateSchemaTask.java:54)
    at io.trino.execution.DataDefinitionExecution.start(DataDefinitionExecution.java:146)
    at io.trino.execution.SqlQueryManager.createQuery(SqlQueryManager.java:272)
    at io.trino.dispatcher.LocalDispatchQuery.startExecution(LocalDispatchQuery.java:150)
    at io.trino.dispatcher.LocalDispatchQuery.lambda$waitForMinimumWorkers$2(LocalDispatchQuery.java:134)
    at io.airlift.concurrent.MoreFutures.lambda$addSuccessCallback$12(MoreFutures.java:570)
    at io.airlift.concurrent.MoreFutures$3.onSuccess(MoreFutures.java:545)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1137)
    at io.trino.$gen.Trino_450____20240627_164623_2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:462)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:175)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1507)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1422)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy416.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1346)
    at  com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1157)

My Minio object store is secured and I have a certificate and key from an established CA.
My Dockerfiles for both Hive and Trino add the certificate to the Java trusted cert store, e.g.:
    RUN mkdir /opt/trino
    RUN mkdir /opt/trino/certs

    COPY public.crt /opt/trino/certs/public.crt
    RUN $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias miniocert -file /opt/trino/certs/public.crt -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt

So both images should have the correct certificate in the correct location to use - 1st assumption - but I may well be wrong, SSL and Java are not my forte.
My Trino config.properties is as follows:
    coordinator=true
    node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true

    http-server.https.enabled=true
    http-server.https.port=8443
    http-server.http.port=8080
    http-server.https.keystore.path=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-jdk-22.0.1+8/lib/security/cacerts
    http-server.https.keystore.key=changeit
    discovery.uri=http://trino:8080

    log.path=/var/log/trino/server.log
    http-server.log.path=/var/log/trino/http-request.log`

And I've tried a few different flavours of this but to no avail.
My metastore-site.xml contains the following nodes:
    <property>
     <name>hive.server2.use.SSL</name>
     <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
     <name>hive.server2.ssl.keystore.path</name>
     <value>/usr/local/openjdk-8/lib/security/cacerts</value>
    </property>

    <property>
     <name>hive.server2.ssl.keystore.password</name>
     <value>changeit</value>
    </property>

    <property>
     <name>hive.metastore.ssl.truststore.path</name>
     <value>/usr/local/openjdk-8/lib/security/cacerts</value>
    </property>

    <property>
     <name>hive.metastore.ssl.truststore.password</name>
    <value>changeit</value>
    </property>

Everything is running through Docker with the primary images being minio:latest (currently 450), apache/hive:4.0.0, trinodb/trino:latest, and mysql:8.0.28.
Also of note is that I'm using v3.3.0 of the AWS Hadoop library (hadoop-aws-3.3.0.jar) and v1.12.750 of the Amazon S3 Java SDK (aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.12.750.jar).
Any pointers as to where to look next would be greatly appreciate. I don't know enough about the stack yet to be able to confidently read the stack trace and know where I need to focus my attention. The link in issue could be between any of the 3 primary modules, I'm just not sure which.
Thanks
